# Difficult integral: $\int e^x \ln (x)\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve an integral:

$\int e^x \ln(x)\,\mathrm dx =\ ?$

I have tried integration by parts and I found out that this method doesn't provide a solution in this case? How to solve it then?

Comment: See [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Answer (score 3):

$$\int e^x\ln xdx=e^x\ln x-\int\frac{e^x}xdx=e^x\ln x-\text{Ei}(x).$$

Comment: That should be $+\text{Ei}(x)$, not $-\text{Ei}(x)$.

Comment: @JohnMoeller: Both *Mathematica* and [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+e%5Ex%2Fx) seem to agree with my result. If you let $x\to-t$, then the two minus signs will cancel each other out.

Comment: Hm, I'm having a hard time trusting Ei as an indefinite integral here. But sure, I'll give Alpha some leeway.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{\rm E_{i}}\left(x\right)}$ must be a  definite Integral:
$\displaystyle{\large{\rm E_{i}}\left(x\right) = {\rm P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{x}{{\rm e}^{t} \over t}\,{\rm d}t}$ with $\displaystyle{\large x\not=0}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: All indefinite integrals are definite ones; e.g. $\displaystyle\int e^xdx=\int_{-\infty}^xe^tdt$. Similarly, $\displaystyle\int\frac{e^x}xdx=$ $=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{e^t}tdt=\text{Ei(x)}$.